# Number box that user cannot type in?

Tags: html, textbox, numbers

I have a number box that goes from 0 to 7.2 with increments of 0.6

How do I make it so they can only change the value of the box by pressing up and down on the arrow keys of the box? for example 5.0 is not an acceptable number because it is not divisible by 0.6. I am trying to avoid having an error occur and forcing the user to try again.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to use a non-editable container here (`<span>`, for example), and update its contents based on the user's actions.

Comment: Is there a way to get that similar type button? The stacked on top of each other button?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/peSHV/)?

Comment: smaller. http://jsfiddle.net/Khamey/peSHV/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on using the number input control, ala

```
<input type="number" id="numberControl" min="0" max="7.2" step="0.6">
```

Your best bet, is when an invalid value is provided you just round to the nearest value.
That can be done with a little jquery with

```
$("#numberControl").change(function(){
   var base = Math.round($("#numberControl").val() / 0.6);
   $("#numberControl").val(base * 0.6);
});
```